# Resample daily time series data with half hour start time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The raw data is like

```
createdAt                    volume
2020-07-20T21:01:08.939Z       2
2020-07-21T15:15:08.939Z       1
2020-07-21T21:34:08.939Z       3
2020-07-28T19:15:08.939Z       4
```

What I want is to calculate the sum of transactions in a 24-hour interval and in my case, the starting time of a day is defined as 16:30. The result should be like

```
createdAt                    volume
2020-07-21T16:30:00.000Z       3
2020-07-22T16:30:00.000Z       3
2020-07-29T16:30:00.000Z       4
```

I'm using `df.resample('24H', base=16).sum()`, but this method can only calculate from 16:00 rather than 16:30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resampling is good for adding new rows, but `pd.Grouper` is good for summarizing existing ones in a different date/time interval. use `pd.Grouper` with `freq=24h` and `base=16.5`:

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'createdAt': {0: '2020-07-20T21:01:08.939Z',
  1: '2020-07-21T15:15:08.939Z',
  2: '2020-07-21T21:34:08.939Z',
  3: '2020-07-28T19:15:08.939Z'},
```

'volume': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 4}})

code:

```
df['createdAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['createdAt'])
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='createdAt' , freq='24H', base=16.5))['volume'].sum().reset_index()
df1 = df1.loc[df1['volume'] != 0]
df1
```

output:

```
    createdAt                       volume
0   2020-07-20 16:30:00+00:00       3
1   2020-07-21 16:30:00+00:00       3
8   2020-07-28 16:30:00+00:00       4
```

Comment: Thank you, David. I just fixed it with `df.resample('1440T', base=990).sum()`, but `pd.Grouper` looks better. I relied to much on `resample()` ;\

Comment: no problem @ZephaniahIrvine please accept as solution if helpful. Thanks.